# Programming Micro controllers using Arduino ISP

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, atmel

Can I burn my Arduino Code into this:

http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAM3A4C

or something similar by just using just the Arduino ISP?

Comment: Arduino ISP is meant to program **AVR** microcontrollers. AFAIK, almost every AVR can be programmed this way, but other microcontroller families (ARM, PIC...) will most probably not work.

Answer (score 1):

Page does nog exist (404).

Also, to run actual Arduino code on it, you'll most likely have to port the Arduino library, if this hasn't been done before.

You may opt for something as easy as a teensy 3.2, they probably meet your requirements and work well in combination with Arduino.
Or fetch one of the newer Arduino models that have comparable microcontrollers

If you still want an M3 (without development board?) you'll be entering a somewhat advanced usecase, in which you probably don't even want to rely on or use Arduino. There are far better IDE's.

Comment: Can you go to that website please.

Comment: I want to use that [chip](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAM3A4C) using the [Arduino ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoISP)

Comment: Ah okay, is that chip mounted on a board/PCB? Or are you simply looking for something like the due https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDue which has a cortex m3

Comment: On a adapter board.

Comment: Hmm, the datasheet doesn't mention ICSP,  I don't think it's compatible, since ARM based boards are mich different.

Comment: So with what kind of boards do you think I can use.

Comment: Can we do something like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/75)

Comment: Read the section about bootloader ROM on this chip.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that chip I think this one also can be done as some of the other chips can be programmed using the Arduino ISP  I think it can be even done for this one. This [one](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/programming.html) uses an AVR ISP Programmer while we are using the Arduino one but as they have similar working It is maybe possible. For example this [one](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/programming.html)